# CoreUI-free-react-admin-template Not Working

Tags: reactjs

I have followed the installation guide on https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template
but I when I try to run:

```
> npm start
```

I get the following message

```
> npm ERR! missing script: start
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\morso\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-02T00_49_20_439Z-debug.logenter code here
```

I think the log pretty much says all is ok but "missing script: start". Let me know if it helps for me to share it.

Note that I have already done the following:

- Tried uninstalling and reinstalling the  CoreUI

  > npm uninstall
  > npm install

But to no avail. The same problem still persist. Btw, I am using Windows 10 system.

I will appreciate the community's help on this.

Update 12-2-2020 - Below is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "@coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template",
  "version": "3.1.1",
  "description": "CoreUI React Open Source Bootstrap 4 Admin Template",
  "author": {
    "name": "CoreUI",
    "url": "https://coreui.io",
    "github": "https://github.com/coreui",
    "twitter": "https://twitter.com/core_ui"
  },
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "CoreUI Team",
      "url": "https://github.com/orgs/coreui/people"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": ".",
  "copyright": "Copyright 2017-2020 creativeLabs Łukasz Holeczek",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/chartjs": "^2.0.0",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^3.4.0",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@coreui/icons-react": "^1.0.2",
    "@coreui/react": "^3.3.4",
    "@coreui/react-chartjs": "^1.0.1",
    "@coreui/utils": "^1.3.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "auto-changelog": "~2.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "~4.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:cov": "npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "test:debug": "react-scripts --inspect-brk test --runInBand",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "changelog": "auto-changelog --starting-version 3.0.0 --commit-limit false --hide-credit"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/issues"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 10",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/*index.js",
      "!src/serviceWorker.js",
      "!src/polyfill.js"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10",
    "npm": ">=6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you `cd`d into the correct directory? Could you update the question with your `package.json` file?

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. Yes, I believe I `cd` into the correct directory. I just edited the question to include the package.json file for your review.